# Requesting a word or idiom for "impressive failure."

Tags: single-word-requests, idiom-requests, phrase-requests

I'm looking for a more formal expression or word that indicates failure to the extent that one would have to work very hard to achieve it.  I'm aware of the idiom "epic fail" but I'm looking for something not as common, casual, or unkind. [Edit/question augmentation]: An example might be getting a negative score on a test for which a "zero" score was previously thought to be the worst outcome.

Comment: Do you mean a failure that turns to your advantage or teaches you something? Or do you mean people perceive it as an impressive effort?

Comment: @vickyace, not exactly - I'm referring more to a situation in which a highly unexpected negative outcome has been achieved.  An  example might be getting a negative score for a test on which a "zero" score was previously thought to be the worst outcome.

Comment: One doesn't work hard in order to fail, but some failures would indeed take a lot of work to duplicate. One that comes to mind is a Soviet Venus probe (Venera 14) that landed on Venus, popped its camera lens cap off, then tried to gauge Venusian soil compressibility. The only thing the sample arm tested was the lens cap, and it was a one-shot deal. The camera worked fine, you can look up the photos.

Comment: There is, of course *[SNAFU](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/310614/is-using-the-word-snafu-instead-of-the-word-problem-correct)*, but it's not necessarily reserved for "impressive" cases.

Comment: A good single-word option is _debacle_. Among the definitions that _Merriam-Webster's Eleventh Collegiate Dictionary_ gives for it are "a violent disruption (as of an army) : ROUT," "a great disaster," and "a complete failure : FIASCO." Interestingly, the original meaning of _debacle_, according to MW, was "a tumultuous breakup  of ice in a river."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've seen media use the term **spectacular failure** for something that *really* failed:

http://www.wired.com/1999/12/a-century-of-spectacular-failure/
https://www.entrepreneur.com/video/274191
http://www.fastcompany.com/3026253/dialed/5-famous-entrepreneurs-who-learned-from-their-first-spectacular-failures
http://www.huffingtonpost.ca/peggy-nash/ndp-needs-leader-who-can-inspire_b_9619998.html

Answer (score 3):

**to crash and burn**

> 1. Lit. [for a plane or car] to crash and burst into flames. The small plane crashed and burned just after it took off.
> 2. **Fig. to fail spectacularly**. *Poor Chuck really crashed and burned when he made his presentation at the sales meeting.*
>
> — 
>   [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/crash+and+burn)

Answer (score 2):

The current neologism is [*omnishambles*](https://www.google.co.uk/search?num=40&safe=active&site=&source=hp&q=omnishambles&oq=omnishambles).

It describes a failure situation which has absolutely no redeeming features.

Originally used in a BBC political drama "*The Thick Of It*", it has been used in Parliament to describe Government policy.

The Oxford English Dictionary gave it the title "Word of the Year" in 2012.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be formal I suggest "comprehensive failure" (which I think suggests that the failure covers every aspect of the task at hand and thus meets the "hard to achieve" criterion).

Answer (score 0):

I'll offer **magnificent failure**. It shows up occasionally. It appears in the Royal Society's Proceedings.

[image: Proceedings of the Royal Society of London, Volume 54]

Proceedings of the Royal Society of London, Volume 54

That would be George Green, btw. Virtually unknown outside of Cambridge during his lifetime, his mathematical discoveries ended up underpinning classical mechanics for a century.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest "abysmal":

> extremely bad; appalling

Cited from: https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/abysmal

Answer (score 0):

**flameout**

connotation is momentary spectacular brilliance, like a meteor's tail, but then quickly "flaming out" into a dud.

Comment: This seems good but is lacking references. Could you cite the dictionary you've used?

Comment: Maybe i didn't read the rules properly, or at all. I took it from my own vocabulary. .... It's Dec 4th 2016, haven't you heard? We live in a fact-free world.

Answer (score -1):

The word "awe-inspiring" would show that it is impressive, without being rude. One could say "Awe-inspiring {failure, downfall, etc.}"

Comment: Or, even, 'awesome'!

Comment: @Dan That would absolutely work if the situation is established as formal. Otherwise, it could be percieved as the colloquial meaning of "awesome".

Comment: The op asks for a "epic fail type" noun but your word is an adjective that describes something that is such a "epic fail type" noun.

Comment: @vickyace The OP only requested a formal alternative to epic fail. Doesn't awe-inspiring X suffice?

Comment: @bakman329 Does "awe inspiring" mean, or even imply that something was a failure? It cannot. You, might as well use impressive, moving, impactful, reverend, amazing, etc.

Comment: @vickyace OP asked for a formal equivalent to Epic Fail, and that is what i provided. Yes, you could use the words you suggested. Look at the OP, "I'm aware of the idiom "epic fail" but I'm looking for something not as common, casual, or unkind."

Comment: @bakman329 I am going to put it in one sentence: the question asks for a noun but what you provided is an adjective that could be used to describe literally anything and hence is not exclusive to the act of failing.

Comment: @vickyace Yes, it asks for a noun. I provided an adjective to replace epic, and suggested nouns to replace fail. There is no problem with that.